# Why does my Trane only blow cold air when the system is set to Heat?

Tags: heating

The thermostat is set at Heat at about 69 but it doesn't warm up. Stays at 65. Just blowing cold air. I had someone come out to look at my Trane XB80, and he said it was probably a bad gas valve. It is receiving a signal to open, it ignites, 10 sec later it turns off. He said it would be about $400 to fix. Does this sound like the problem?

Comment: A bad gas valve could surely cause the flame to go out, however, the furnace should shut down and try to restart if there's no flame

Comment: Are there any diagnostic lights or displays on the furnace? How long does the fan run once the flame goes out?